# Ck editor file uploading - getting internal server error 500

Tags: joomla, ckeditor, ckfinder

We have a web site with domain http://209.59.154.150/~phnxaudi/,.
To develop this website we have used Joomla framework, and we have used Ckeditor in it, for uploading files(pdf, images etc ).
Also we have installed Ckeditor in the server.

But for some reason we are getting an internal 500 server error.
Could anyone please help us to solve this issue?

Comment: What file browser/upload component are you using. ckeditor 3.0+ does not have one built in by default.

Comment: how can i know which version of ck editor is installed in my server?

Comment: CKEditor 3.0 (revision 4148), this is what we are using
But its working perfectly in our local machine

and its not working in site server

Comment: Is it ck or fck, they changed it to ck at 3.0 release. In FCK editor there is a file fckeditor.js and there is a property called FCKeditor.prototype.Version that has the version number, and ckeditor has a ckeditor.js which has the version in the first line. You can see it even though it is minified.

Comment: means Ckfinder and Ckeditor version is 3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have gotten 500 errors from ckFinder. It almost always is permissions. Ensure that the internet user has read/directory browse/write permissions to the configured "user files" folder.

Comment: upvoted, thanks.  for me CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH didn't exist. mkdir fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the "*.htaccess*" file in the ckeditor root directory. This caused the error at our server.

Comment: It would be more helpful to describe the contents of .htaccess so we can determine which line(s) caused the problem. (There's no .htaccess file in my CKEditor root directory so this didn't solve the problem for me anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

if that's dont work, try to gave 0755 permission to the connector file in core....
when you put your files in the server automatically give 0777 permissions, and I can't execute php file, ...

try with a "hello world" en ckfinder folder and you can see the problem of permission.

sorry for my bad english.

enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the ".htaccess" file in the ckeditor root directory. This caused the error at our server.   by Wim Van Loon < this solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Does the filename contain non-standard characters?  Does it have no extension?  I've found that if either of those are true, the image will not upload, the logs show nothing, and the CKEditor image upload interface shows a 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with my ck_editor app, I was getting a similar type of error.

[image]

I tried copying demo application from django-ckeditor repository [ck-editor demo application](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor)

with all the settings.
I faced two types of errors:-

1. Not mentioning upload path in the root urls

   path('upload/', ImageUploadView.as_view(), name="upload")

   import ImageUploadView from the ckeditor_uploader.views
2. I selected ckeditor_uploader's pillowbackend
   This [forum](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/18369/) was quite useful to solve this problem.
   [image]

   which should have been something like

   [image]

Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

i get this error

after install ckeditor and add the ckuploader '

Note: don't forget before you do the upload to run this commend:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

you need to get this folder in your project and on it you find this ckeditor folder:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rEmC.png)

I do this settings and it worked for me:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S03BJ.png)

if you don't work with you just search on youtube
how to upload images in django - ckeditor

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my Ruby on Rails app, and this solved it for me:
Try adding the configuration:

```
    config.filebrowserUploadMethod = "form"
```

I have it in `ckeditor_config.js.coffee`
But you should add it wherever you have the `config.filebrowserUploadUrl` set or anything that resembles that config